# Разбить строку на слова БЕЗ регулярных выражений

Tags: java, строки, substring

```
    public class SequentialWordsNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Это просто текст, для примера работы программы";
        System.out.println(sequentialWordsNumbers(str));
    }

    public static String sequentialWordsNumbers(String text){
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int num = 0;
        String word = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            if (text.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                word = word + text.charAt(i);
            } else {
                num++;
                stringBuilder.append(" (" + num + ") " + word);
                word = "";
            }
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Код должен строку делить на слова без регулярных выражений.

Задание такое:
Нужно написать метод sequentialWordsNumbers, который в качестве аргумента принимает текст и перед каждым словом пишет его порядковый номер в круглых скобках и возвращает строку. Метод необходимо написать без использования регулярных выражений. Пример того, как оно должно работать:

Введите текст:
Это просто текст, для примера работы программы
Результат:
(1) Это (2) просто (3) текст, (4) для (5) примера (6) работы (7) программы

Результат моего кода такой (как и требует задание):
(1) Это (2) просто (3) текст, (4) для (5) примера (6) работы (7) программы

Я в процессе изучения Java. Это одно из заданий. Тестирование не проходит. Добавляю скрин с автотестированием. Подскажите, плз, на что обратить внимание?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возьмите строку например String charsYouDontNeed = "вставляете туда все символы, которыми разделяются слова в строке", затем делаете charsYouDontNeed.toCharArray(), и потом циклом проходите по этому массиву, и если символ равен не букве, то просто пропускаете его.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.

Comment: Я бы добавил только, что ориентироваться лучше на пробел, т.к. слова могут содержать дефисы, заканчиваться знаками препинания, либо содержать цифры.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String sequentialWordsNumbers(String text) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int num = 0;
        String word = "";
        String newText = text.trim() + " ";
        if (text == "") {
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < newText.length(); i++) {
                if (newText.length() <= 2 && !Character.isLetter(newText.charAt(i))) {
                    word = "";
                }
                if (newText.charAt(i) != ' ' && newText.length() > 2) {
                    word = word + newText.charAt(i);
                } else {
                    num++;
                    stringBuilder.append(" (" + num + ") " + word);
                    word = "";
                }
            }
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
    }
```

Это решение прошло тестирование!!

Answer (score 0):

большое спасибо за правильную идею. Если бы не  stringBuilder.append(" (" + num + ") " + word); никогда бы в жизни не догадался. И так крутил и этак.Сначала добавлял счетчик вначале текста, потом внутри цикла. Еще раз огромное спасибо. Но данный код излишне  большой и нерациональный. Я сделал так:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
       int end  = text.indexOf(' ' ,start);
       if (end == -1) {
       sb.append(`введите сюда код`(" (" + count + ") " + 
        text.substring(start)));
           return sb.toString().trim();
       }
        text.substring(start, end);
        sb.append((" (" + count + ") " +text.substring(start, end)));
        count++;
        start = end + 1;
    }
    return sb.toString().trim();
```

Тест пройден